# How to use react bootstrap theme in other css files

Tags: css, reactjs, themes, react-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to use theme colors from my custom react-bootstrap theme in my other CSS files. I specifically am trying to change the color of my header text to be the primary color I have defined in my bootstrap theme. In the past I have used material-ui with react where I was able to use the makeStyles and pass the theme as a parameter and use it that way, but I can't seem to find a way of doing that with bootstrap. How would I use do something like

```
div {
   color: theme.primary
}
```

just trying to figure out how to utilize the react-bootstrap theme in the best possible way so I can write less CSS.

Comment: i have same problem did you find any solution